# The Karoubi model structure on Cat

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

I am looking for any kind of informations about the Karoubi model structure on $\bf Cat$. I discovered the presence of this structure a few months ago on the [Joyal Lab](http://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Model+structures+on+Cat#the_karoubian_model_structure) and now I would like to use it as an example in a lecture.

Any kind of information which is not present on the page (which I find an extremely dry account of the properties of the Karoubi structure) is welcome! Examples of questions I'm interested in:

i) Can well-known categorical properties be rephrased in homotopical jargon? How is a set of generating trivial cofibration made?
ii) Cauchy-complete categories are the fibrant objects; Cauchy completion the fibrant replacement: has this fact some heavy consequences in terms of properties of Cauchy complete categories?

Comment: I describe the model structure [here](http://semmibol.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/the-morita-model-structure-on-cat/). There is just one extra generating trivial cofibration, namely the inclusion of the free idempotent into the free split idempotent.

Comment: Actually, the generating trivial cofibration is clearly described as such in your link to Joyal's CatLab.

Comment: Woops, I meant generating *fibration*, my bad. But Zhen's Lin(k) solves the problem, as always.. The next question should have been "is Karoubi a localization of the standard model structure?"

Comment: (Do you know whether Joyal is going to finish that note?)

Comment: Yes, it is a left Bousfield localisation of the canonical model structure, almost by definition. The generating cofibrations are therefore the same as for the canonical model structure.